# Programmatically get the latest Java version supported by the current version of Gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build, automation

my current problem is the following: I would like to be able to detect which is **the latest *officially supported* java version for the version of Gradle I am currently using** for building some project.
I could not find an API for that, `GradleVersion` does not provide information about the maximum supported Java toolchain.
The only place where I found the information is in the Javadoc documentation of `JavaVersion.java`:

```java
...
    /**
     * Java 16 major version.
     *
     * @since 6.3
     */
    VERSION_16,

    /**
     * Java 17 major version.
     * Not officially supported by Gradle. Use at your own risk.
     *
     * @since 6.3
     */
    VERSION_17,
...
```

versions not yet supported have a `Not officially supported by Gradle. Use at your own risk.` line, but detecting the maximum supported version this way is too fragile for my scopes.

In other words, I'd like to able to write the following Kotlin extension function:

```kotlin
/**
  * Returns 16 for Gradle 7.2, Returns 13 for Gradle 6.0, etc.
  */
fun GradleVersion.latestSupportedJava(): JavaVersion = ...
```

For my scopes, it is perfectly fine if the function can be defined only for Gradle 7.2+ (namely, if it uses an API that is not there in previous versions of Gradle).

---

I'm adding a detail: the less-worse method I've found to this moment is to scrape this URL: docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html that still is rather fragile.
This function works, but, as said, is fragile by design, even forgetting that scraping pages via Regex is not a good idea in general.

```kotlin
fun latestSupportedJava(): JavaLanguageVersion =
    Regex("""<tr.*>[\s|\n|\r]*<td.*>.*?(\d+).*?<\/td>[\s|\n|\r]*<td.*>.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)).*?<\/td>""")
        .findAll(URL("https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html").readText())
        .map {
            val (javaVersion, gradleVersion) = it.destructured
            JavaLanguageVersion.of(javaVersion) to GradleVersion.version(gradleVersion)
        }
        .filter { (_, gradleVersion) -> GradleVersion.current() >= gradleVersion }
        .maxByOrNull { (_, gradleVersion) -> gradleVersion }
        ?.first
        ?: JavaLanguageVersion.of(16)
```

---

Update: I opened a [feature request](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18141) to the Gradle folks.

Comment: I'm adding a detail: the less-worse method I've found to this moment is to scrape this URL: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html that still is rather fragile.

Comment: Can you share the use case you're thinking about? Do you have a build system which receives Java code and you want to reject the compilation if the Java version of this code is higher than what you support?

Comment: Much simpler. I am trying to write a build file (and, possibly, a Gradle plugin) that leverages the new Gradle [Toolchains for Java](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html) to compile for one Java version and test for all the subsequent versions; I am currently testing the approach on a Gradle plugin, so the tests must be limited to the Gradle Toolkit version in use.

Comment: Ok, clear. It doesn't look like Gradle exposes the compatibility matrix into an API so I guess you won't have any better way than scraping the value as you're already doing. However, I suggest you add both comments of yours in the body of the question as they sound pretty relevant to reply the question and not everybody reads the comments.